Where exactly is the friction with the pipe walls and the fluid?

Is the friction between the walls of the pipe and the no slip layer? Or is it between the no slip layer and the rest of the fluid above?

Maybe this will help; https://fm-nitk.vlabs.ac.in/exp/friction-in-pipes/theory.html#:~:text=Friction%20loss%20in%20pipe,flow%20is%20laminar%20or%20turbulent.

@JonCuster Not sure how that helps given no answers.

@BobD - that is the automatic comment from flagging as a duplicate, which was asked by the OP yesterday.

@JonCuster Aah, I didn't catch that it was same OP

Wait i deleted that, i wasn't specific enough and so i wanted to post the question again
